# connected users' list in sails socket

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

i've currently started using sailsJS with angularJs at frontend alognwith socket for realtime communiction.

Sailsjs gives built-in support to websocket through "sails.io.js".On client side  after adding this library this code is added to angular's chat controller.

**Client side code**

```
io.socket.get('/chat',{token:token},function(users){
console.log(users);
});
```

chatController's action on sails side is like this.

**Server side code**

```
 chat: function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.isSocket);
 //this gives true when called through client.
})
```

infact very new to sails so i want suggestion that how to maintain connected user's list because m not using redis as storage purpose.adapter is memory.array is not a good idea because it'll vanish when restart a server.m using sails version of 0.11.0.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat new but learning fast, these suggestions should get you there unless someone else responds with greatness...

They changed it in 11 but in 10.5 I use sockets.js in config folder and on connect I store the session data in an array with their socket. 
I created a service in APIs/service that contains the array and socket associate function.

For v11 you can't do that exactly the same, but you can make  your first 'hello' from the client call a function in a controller that calls the associate function.

A couple tips would be don't let the client just tell you who they are, as in don't just take the username from the params but get it from req.session

(This assumes you have user auth setup)

In my case I have
in **api/services/Z.js**      (putting the file here makes it's functions globally accessible)

```
var socketList = []; 
module.exports = {
associateSocket: function(session, socket) { // send in your username(string) socket(object) id(mongoId) and this will push to the socketlist for lookups
    sails.log.debug("associate socket called!",socketList.length)
    var iHateYou = socketList
    //DEBUG
    var sList = socketList
    var util = require('util')
    if (session.authenticated){
        var username = session.user.auth.username
        var userId = session.user.id
        // sails.log.debug("Z: associating new user!",username,userId,socket)
        if (username && socket && userId) {
            sList[sList.length]= {
                username: session.user.auth.username,
                socket: socket,
                userId: session.user.id,
            };
            sails.log.debug('push run!!! currentsocketList length',socketList.length)
        } else sails.log("Z.associateSocket called with invalid data", username, userId, authId, socket)
    }else{sails.log.warn("Z.associateSocket: a socket attempted to associate itself without being logged in")}
},
```

}

in my **config/sockets.js**

```
onConnect: function(session, socket) {
    Z.associateSocket(session,socket)
    if (session.user && session.user.auth){
      sails.log("config/sockets.js: "+session.user.auth.username+" CONNECT! session:",session)
    }else sails.log.warn('connect called on socket without an auth, the client thinks it already has a session, so we need to fix this')

    // By default, do nothing.
  },
```

Then you can make add some functions to your services file to do lookups based on username and passwords, remove sockets that are disconnecting and the like (I'm using waterlock for my auth at the moment, although debating the switch back to sails-generate-auth)

Comment: in version 0.11 there is beforeConnect instead of onConnect according to migration guide.but it isn't working while onConnect works despite of giving error or deprecation.anyhow at this point,onConnect is called before login while i m working with tokens which are created after authentication.so m calling a _chatController's_ action and sending token in query parameterz.

Comment: Yes thats the place for sure.  So you solved your problem? Or still need more info?

Comment: still need info cz i've failed to customize these events that's why m using routes of ocntroller instead of these built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `onConnect` and dicconnect function from `config/sockets.js`.